# How to put 2D frame-by-frame animation on 3d model (hybrid animation)

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, libgdx, shader, 3d-modelling

I'd like to do a cartoony 3D character, where the facial features are flat-drawn and animated in 2D. Sort of like the Bubble Guppies characters.

I'm struggling with finding a good method to do it. I'm using Libgdx, but I think the potential methodologies could apply to any game engine.

Here are ideas I thought of, but each has drawbacks. Is there a way this is commonly done? I was just playing a low-budget Wii game with my kids (a Nickelodeon dancing game) that uses this type of animation for the faces.

***Ideas:***

**UV animation** - Is there a way to set up a game model (FBX format) so that certain UV's are stored in various skins? Then the UV's could jump around to various places in a sprite map.

**Projected face** - This idea is convoluted. Use a projection of a texture onto the model with a vertex shader uniform that shifts the UV's of the projected texture around. So basically, you'd need a projection matrix that's set up to move the face projection around with the model. But you'd need enough padding around the face frame sprites to keep the rest of the model clear of other parts of the sprite map. And this results in a complicated fragment shader that would not be great for mobile.

**Move flat 3D decal with model** - Separately show a 3D decal that's lined up with the model and batched as a separate mesh in the game. The decal could just be a quad where you change the UV attributes of the vertices on each frame of animation. However, this method won't wrap around the curvature of a face. Maybe it could be broken down to separate decals for each eye and the mouth, but still wouldn't look great, and require creating a separate file to go with each model to define where the decals go.

**Separate bone for each frame of animation** - Model a duplicate face in the mesh for every frame of animation, and give each a unique bone. Animate the face by toggling bone scales between zero and one. This idea quickly breaks down if there are more than a few frames of animation.

**Update part of skin each frame** - Copy the skin into an FBO. Draw the latest frame of animation into the part of the FBO color texture that contains the face. Downsides to this method are that you'd need a separate copy of the texture in memory for every instance of the model, and the FBO would have to either do a buffer restore every frame (costly) or you'd have to redraw the entire skin into the FBO each frame (also costly).

I have other ideas that are considerably more difficult than these. It feels like there must be an easier way.

---

**Edit:**

One more idea... **Uniform UV offset and vertex colors** - This method would use vertex colors since they are easily supported in all game engines and modeling packages, but in many cases are unused. In the texture, create a strip of the frames of animation. Set up the face UV's for the first frame. Color all vertices with Alpha 0 except the face vertices, which can be colored Alpha 1. Then pass a UV face offset uniform to the vertex shader, and multiply it by a step function on the vertex colors before adding it to the UVs. This avoids the downsides of all the above methods: everything could be wrapped into one texture shared by all instances of the model, and there would be no two-pass pixels on the model except possibly where the face is. The downside here is a heftier model (four extra attributes per vertex, although perhaps the color could be baked down to a single byte).

Answer (score 0):

Your shader could receive 2 textures, one for the body, and one for the face. The face one being transparent so you could overlay it on top of the body one. Then you just need to send a different face texture based on the animation.

Comment: This might be the easiest way to do it. But a couple of downsides...the frames of animation cannot be atlased onto a single texture, so if there are very many instances of the character on screen there will be a lot of texture binding going on. Also there will be two texture look-ups for every pixel of the character even though only the face needs two visually. Kind of expensive for mobile. I think my decal idea and my bones idea would be more performant, but more difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same problem with implementing a 2d animation to a background billboard in my 3d scene.

I believe that Using Decals is the simplest solution, and implementing the animation is as easy as updating the decal’s TextureRegion according to an Animation object:

```
TextureRegion frame = animation.getKeyFrame(currentFrameTime, true);
decal.setTextureRegion (frame);
```

I guess the real problem in your case is positioning the decal inside the scene.
One solution could be using your 3D modeling software for modeling a "phantom" mesh that will store the position of the decal.

The "phantom" mesh will not be rendered with all the other 3d elements, instead it will be used to determine the position of the decals vertices. The only thing you’ll need to do is copy the “phantom” position vertices and paste them to the decal.

I hadn’t got to implement this solution yet, but theoretically it could be relatively easily done.

Hope this idea will help you, and I will appreciate you sharing other solutions/code to this problem if you find any.